# Doesn't give me the class of parent class as it should

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code.

```
<div data-bind="click: callMe2" class="parent">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorrs">Test</a>
</div>
```

All I'm trying to do is get the class of the div element on Test link click. But instead I'm getting the class of the anchor element even though the data is bound to the div element. Am I missing something? I could achieve that with .parent() from jquery but I don't want to take that approach.

Here's the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/euw8z/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the event object `target` points to the original element which triggered the event - in this case the `a` element, if you want to get the element to which the handler is bound to then use the property `currentTarget`

```
var viewModel = {
    callMe2: function(item,event){
        var $self = $(event.currentTarget).attr("class");
        //var $parent = $(event.target).parent().attr("class");
        alert($self);
        //alert($parent);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XQXyn/)